# Page curl effect for Activities in Android

Tags: android, page-curl

I need page curl effect for Activities in Android as in iPhone.

I checked the following links

http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/

But both are useful for Bitmap (Images) only but i need curling effect at startActivity() i.e, when i am going for new Activity.

Is it possible ? and how ?

Comment: didn't tried for it yet..but as you got code for image,can you try convert your linearlayout/relative into Bitmap and then show curl-effect and then show next activity?..sorry no specific ideas..but commenting to boost you that you can atleast give a try,,

Comment: In hopes that this is the target implementation I provide you the following link. http://tinyurl.com/7k3tqr8

Comment: With Jelly Bean (Android 4.1) they have added animations between Activity changes. And I think Jake Warthon implemented a support version of it to use on older SDKs. 
I don't know how to implement the animation tough. Just an idea.

Comment: I unsuccessfully tried to do this for activity... let me kno if it works out for u

Answer (score 15):

@surendra

Here is one good example explaining how you can add page curl to activity...

http://devappandroid.com/android-beginner/page-curlturn-effect-android

Comment: i didn't see PageCurlEffect.java in the link.. where can i get it

Comment: i am also not find PageCurlEffect.java file.

Comment: @Brajendra Pandey, you have to register to see the download link

Comment: @dimetil not available even after registration !